# What kind of laptop should I be using: Alienware or Macbook Pro?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, video-editor, laptop

I'm planning to buy a new laptop since my current PC(Lenovo U430) is kind of slow when it comes to gaming and video editing. My current budget is $1,000 to $1,500, after researching, I chose these brands: Alienware 13 inch(latest model) and Macbook Pro 13 inch(with retina display) only.**Question: Which brand or model should I be buying that is compatible and worth it for a little gaming and video editing**(no lagging while editing or checking the video preview in After Effects or Premiere Pro) **with my current budget**?

Here's the link to Alienware 13 inch list of models:
http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/alienware-13-laptop?~ck=mn

Here's the link to Macbook Pro 13 inch list of models:
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=macbook+pro+retina+display+13&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&af=true&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys

Comment your answer with the link or the brand and specs of the model.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Recommending a particular brand is off topic here - it comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using Premiere, [Adobe recommends](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html) 16GB of RAM and a minimum of 8GB. They minimum RAM for [After Effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/system-requirements.html) is less, but there are some other equally important things to consider. I'd also recommend spending as much as you can on as much SSD storage as you can afford.

Check the specs of the software you want to use for editing - particularly the minimum RAM and the kind of Graphics processor (GPU). If you want to use [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) for editing (it is FREE) and color correcting - you'll want all the RAM you can get.

If you are comfortable with the hardware, I'd recommend a Dell or HP laptop as you will likely find more affordable options for RAM, GPU and SSD than what Apple offers. I don't know much about gaming, but I understand Windows solutions are what the kids dig. FWIW I am plugging along on an 11" mid-2012 i7 AirBook and it does alright with an external monitor out the Thunderport. I edit with Resolve, iMovie, & [LightWorks](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=download&Itemid=206) and move pixels about with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). Nothing fancy or long-form, but I'd much prefer a 15" screen.